# comparing two functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am working on some problem and got stuck at one point:

I need to show that if $f(t)=(\log t)^2$ and $g(t)=\frac{(\log \sqrt{x})^2}{\sqrt{x}-1}(t-1)$, then $f\ \ge g\ $ for any $1\le t \le \sqrt{x}$.

I guess it is true from their graphs and they intersect at $(1,0)$ and $(\sqrt{ x} ,\ (\log \sqrt{x})^2 \ )$ .  I just don't know how to explain that in words or in some algebraic way why $f\ \ge g\ $ for any $1\le t \le \sqrt{x}$.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$f(t)$ is concave down on $1 \leq t \leq \sqrt{x}$, and $g(t)$ is a secant line. It follows that $f(t) \geq g(t)$ on this interval.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think $f$ is concave down on the whole interval:  $f''(t)=\frac{2-2\log t}{t^2}$ is negative only for $t>e$. So what if $1<t<\sqrt{x}<e$? Am I missing something? Do I need to put a condition on $x$ for this to work?  Or is there another way other than "concavity" of $f$ to show the inequality?

Comment: Hm, no, you're right. I actually think the inequality isn't true. Because $f'(1) = 0$, and $g'(1) > 0$, for $t$ near $1$ we should have $f \leq g$. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Actually my professor used it to estimate some integral. I found another estimate for the integral, but I was wondering if this one is true or not. Thanks anyway for your help.